# Drupal 7 add image anywhere I want on my website

Tags: drupal

I want to add 3 country flags in a specific place on my Drupal 7 website. When clicking a iamge it should open a link. Can't use a block because my theme doesn't have the region I need to place those images.
My question is 
1. what is the code to use ?
2. In what file I should place that code ? page.tpl.php ? style.css ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is way too broad a question to be reasonably answered here. There's no single method for adding an image to the arbitrary location of 'anywhere' within your site. Where you want to add it will dictate what templates you need to add/override

Comment: You can hard code those images in a section of your page.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own region and assign a block to it. For guidelines you can read http://drupal.org/node/171205 and http://drupal.org/node/171224.

Comment: I don't want to use a block it will not look right, I just need to add 3 images. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can put your html in page.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways. As pamatt said, you can put the actual content into your page.tpl.php but it will appear on all pages. Add a class or even an ID in this case then you can hide those images if you need to on other pages by using css.

Inspect the code in Firebug, check the body tag and just add one of them specific to whatever page you may want to hide the images from.

like:

```
body.section-about .myThreeImages {display:none;}
```

for instance.

Comment: So, I solved my issue by adding the code below in the page.tpl.php file, in my 19 inch monitor the icons are placed in the right place, but when I opened the website on a 17 inch monitor the icons where place in a wrong place, too far on the left, how to solve this one ? Thank you

<a href="http://www.website.com/en" target="_self">
<img src="http://website.com/images/england.png" border="0" style="position:absolute; top:120px; left:1145px; width:24px; height:24px border:none;max-width:100%;" alt="English Language" />
</a>